# improve speed of pandas to_csv() to write large data to disk

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a large dataframe of size 200 Million rows and 50 Columns. The dataframe contains text as well as numeric data.

I am using pandas to write the dataframe to disk, below is the `to_csv()` function as i am using,

```
df.to_csv("test.csv",index=True,header=True,chunksize=100000)
```

I have read multiple similar threads about this but could not find any suitable answer. Below are the points that i have tried,

- I have already tried multiple times by varying chunksize, using encoding and compressions but none of them give a considerable performance enhancement.
- I have tried writing the files to `tmpfs` (ram disk) as well, but no improvement, providing steps below for further validation,

  `mount -t tmpfs -o size=50000m tmpfs /tmp-disk/`

  and then

  `df.to_csv("/tmp-disk/test.csv",index=True,header=True,chunksize=100000)`

Also, splitting and starting multiple threads is not an option for me here. And I need to output csv only.

Comment: Are the strings in your dataframe often repeated?

Comment: @jpp in some columns yes they are repeated, but for majority of columns, no

Comment: @AkashRanjan You can write the dataframe to SQL table and then export as csv that would be much faster.

Comment: Is `csv.gz` (gzipped csv) not an option?

Comment: @jpp yes it is, and as mentioned in my question i have already tried that as well, but that also doesn't give any considerable performance enhancements

Comment: I second the recommendation by @min2bro.  CSV is not a good format for saving that much data.  If you absolutely have to write CSV, write it to a decent format first and then extract.  Consider SQLite3 or HDF5.